# If I create two files with same content , should their hashes be the same?

Tags: files

What could be the reason ? Aren't there any property of the files that could be responsible to produce different hashes using SHA 256 ?

Creation time is same.modification time is different.

Comment: I see no reason of having different hashes on the same files. The whole idea of hash is to check if content is the same.

Comment: In case of fake certificates , it is useful. Suppose a fake certificate is created like a genuine one and can't be differentiated apparently. Will hash algorithms useful in this case ?

Comment: As far as I know certificates have dates inside the file. Changing them will affect the hash.

Comment: How did you create the two files? Files have to be byte to byte identical. One extra space in a text file with the "same" content will make the difference.

Comment: Certificates is based on [public-private pair of keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), and this is orthogonal to your question about calculating a file hash. This is about content encryption/decryption, not about calculating a content hash.

Comment: @manivarmaindukuri If two certificates have identical hash, they *are* equally valid. This is why MD5 is problematic; it has a uncomfortably high chance of collissions.

Comment: In case of fake degree certificates , suppose a culprit produce a fake degree which resembles a genuine one. I already have hash of original one given by University itself which is genuine. Now ,since culprits degree certificate is fake , can't I detect it as fake by calculating its hash and compare against hash I already have. Content is same in both degree certificates.How to prove it is fake ?

Answer (score 2):

> Aren't there any property of the files that could be responsible to produce different hashes using SHA 256 ?
>
> Creation time is same.modification time is different.

mtime and other file properties is not a part of file content. The "file content" is whatever you can read with ["read" C function](https://linux.die.net/man/3/read). You can also use, for example, `hexdump -C myfile`, which uses `read` function internally, to see the content of a file "myfile". So if it's the same, hashes would also be the same.

Comment: In case of fake degree certificates , suppose a culprit produce a fake degree which resembles  a genuine one. I already have hash of original one given by University itself which is genuine. Now ,since culprits degree certificate is fake , can't I detect it as fake by calculating its hash and compare against hash I already have. Content is same in both degree certificates.How to prove it is fake ?

Comment: If what you call a "fake certificate" has same content as the genuine one, then it's not a fake. Imagine both certificates has been written to a file. So you read them with `read()` function or with `hexdump` utility, and what do you see? If what you see is the same content, then the certificates are the same.